# file(1) 5.28 Invalid argument when using bytes parameter

Tags: files

Release 5.26 of `file(1)` added support for user-defined byte read limit:

```
2016-03-31  13:50  Christos Zoulas <christos@zoulas.com>

    * make the number of bytes read from files configurable.
```

By using `-P` one should be able to set the byte count limit. However, I get a `Invalid argument` error when using the parameter, e.g.:

```
$ file -i --mime-encoding -P bytes=15000 myinput
file: compiled magic version [528] does 
file: Can't set bytes Invalid argument
```

Not sure if related, but I also get a version discrepancy warning when running file: `file: compiled magic version [528] does not match with shared library magic version [524]`

I'm using file 5.28.

```
$ file -v
file-5.28
magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic
```

**EDIT** This is the installation procedure I followed:

1. `./configure`
2. `make`
3. `make check` - no errors
4. `sudo make install`
5. `make installcheck` - no errors

Comment: How do you installed that version? What distribution are you using? I tried to compile it manually myself and works for me.

Comment: @zuazo Downloaded from the ftp (ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/) and compiled following the included instructions. I did, however, `apt-get purge` the package I hade before (v 5.25).

Comment: Please, write the exact procedure you used to compile and install it and the distribution name and version you are using in the question.

Comment: @zuazo I added the steps to my answer. The distribution is the one I linked above in the ftp. Version 5.28.

Comment: Thanks. With *distribution* I mean the Operative System you are using.

Comment: @zuazo Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please add to your post the output of `which file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to remove **libmagic** from your system before installing `file` from sources:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge libmagic1 file
```

Then, to install `file`:

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/file-5.28.tar.gz
$ tar xvzf file-5.28.tar.gz
$ cd file-5.28
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

That worked for me:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
$ file -i --mime-encoding -P bytes=15000 $(which file)
/usr/bin/file: application/x-executable; charset=binary
```